# Windows Crypto API CryptEncrypt with the HashObject

Tags: c, node.js, winapi, cryptography, mscapi

I'm using `Windows API CryptEncrypt with CALG_AES_256` 
I want to use a password to encrypt, from what I understand

```
 1. CryptAcquireContext
 2. CryptCreateHash (CALG_MD5)
 3. CryptHashData
 4. CryptDeriveKey
 5. CryptEncrypt
```

I need to decrypt with `nodejs crypto` & I used `openssl` enc to test `nodejs` 
decrypting was successful but with C code the message is different
How does windows use the hash ?

Comment: Do you have access to CNG?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I'll try them now, I'm developing for Windows 7 so yes I should have access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a password-hash function, not just a normal hash. A password-hash is salted and has a work-factor that makes it harder for an attacker to guess the password using a dictionary attack.

Microsoft has created [an implementation of PBKDF2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd433795%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the CNG framework. [PBKDF2 is also contained in OpenSSL](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC%283%29).